# How do I select a song in a playlist in my library in iTunes 10?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes 9 and earlier, I could go to a playlist and hold down option and click the small arrow next to the name of any song in that playlist to select that song in the main library instead of the playlist. This was very useful, for example if I wanted to remove a song from my library, I could use this to "reveal" the song in the main library and remove it from there.

(This little icon, when clicked on without option, would open the iTunes store for purchasing the selected song)

In iTunes 10, there is no more arrow for me to option click on. How can I select a song in a playlist and go to that same song file in the main library in iTunes 10?

Comment: anytime ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is through the context menu on the selected song. Ctrl + Click (right click), go to the "Show in Playlist" item, and select the "Music" option. You should then be taken to the song in the main library list.

Answer (score 3):

There's an arrow, it's under "ping" (and if you have Ping Disabled the arrow is still there):

[image]

When you click on the "ping" icon:

[image]

Comment: Okay this was a touch one! Your answer had lots of pretty screen shots *and is actually closer to what I asked*, that is, this is the replacement for the previous feature I was asking about. But, Tim answered first, he needs the rep more, and I actually prefer his method (even though I asked how to do it your way!) SO, I had to accept his answer. :-( I upvoted you though!

Comment: @Josh It's fine ;) Glad you found your solution! I upvoted him too.